# MySQL select most recent record IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a Message table that has following two columns:

```
ID
SENT_DATE
```

Say I have the following records ordered by SENT_DATE:

```
ID              SENT_DATE

54              2012-09-21 13:25:20
53              2012-09-21 13:25:17
32              2012-09-21 13:25:15
52              2012-09-21 13:25:14
51              2012-09-21 13:25:12
46              2012-09-21 13:25:12
50              2012-09-21 13:25:11
```

How do I get all new message IDs sent after ID=46 (exclusive)? The query should return the following list:

```
ID

54
53
32
52
51
```

Notice that the message IDs don't increase monotonically overtime, as they are generated by different message queues. But the IDs are unique. Also, two messages can be sent at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to get the `sent_date` of the ID you want and return all rows with a greater value:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `messages` 
WHERE `sent_date` >= (SELECT `sent_date` FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = 46)
AND `id` <> 46
```

Comment: This selects both columns, the OP requested `ID` only

Comment: But what if 50 has the same SENT_DATE? Your query will include 50, which should be excluded, as it is below 46 on the list.

Comment: If both 50 and 51 have the same timestamp of `2012-09-21 13:25:12`, you want to include 51 but not 50? In your example they don't have the same timestamp, so I'm not clear on what you mean. Are you referring to the natural row order?

Answer (score 2):

You can do using a subselect for the sent_date of id 46, like so:

```
select * from message_table where sent_date > (select sent_date from message_table where id = 46)
```

Comment: This will not work. It will exclude message 51, as it has the same SENT_DATE as message 46.

Comment: But the OP wants "message IDs sent after ID=46" so excluding 51 is right.. no? that is what I understood.

Comment: "message IDs sent after ID=46" meaning "any records above 46 on the list". So that will include 51 (right above 46 on the list).

Comment: @scabbage: There is no "after" or "above" in SQL tables. Please define exactly what you want. All rows with same (or later) datetime as row with `id=46` or just those with later datetime?

Comment: @ypercube is correct, the only reason 51 is above 46 and 50 is below is because it is sorted by the sent_date. if you sort by ID for example, it will no longer be the case.

Comment: What I'm doing is creating a running script to poll the db for any new messages. I need a SQL query to fetch the DB for anything received after ID=46. This might be a corner case, but messages could be received with exactly the SENT_DATE (though unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

Using a sub-query will solve this issue.

Handled inclusively:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `messages` WHERE `SENT_DATE` >=
    (SELECT `SENT_DATE` FROM `messages` WHERE `ID` = 46)
```

Handled exclusively:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `messages` WHERE `SENT_DATE` >
    (SELECT `SENT_DATE` FROM `messages` WHERE `ID` = 46)
```